# How to split a string in C# at last parenthesis

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello I need to split a string for example this string:

```
 str.Append("INSERT INTO enquete_antwoord (enquete_vraag_ID, enquete_antwoord, kdv_ID, semesterstart, semestereind, semester) VALUES ('" + reader2["enquete_vraag_ID"].ToString() + "', '" + antwoord + "', '" + id + "', 2013-12-12, 2014-12-12, 1)").ToString();
```

what I need to split is the last )"

But I can't split it:

```
string[] commands = str.Split(new string[] { ")"" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: `what I need to split is the last )"` - I don't get it. Could you show the desired result?

Comment: @KonradMorawski Well str is filling up with queries. I need to split those queries here )"

Comment: Do you mean the only occurrence of )" (as its the last). If so why split, if its there then you know the value it )"

Comment: Why not stop appending more text to the string, and start a new one, instead of attempting to split it afterwards? What if one of the values contains an end parenthesis?

Comment: Even if it didn't, he would still need to split the string on **every second** end parenthesis. You can't do it with `String.Split`, a regex would be needed. Which is getting silly (and risky)

Comment: I hope the input string is not from production code because you're wide open for sql-injection. Use sql-parameters.

Comment: dates aren't going to work either sql will treat them as arithmetic.

Answer (score 3):

I would avoid using a `StringBuilder` (which is what I'm assuming you're using right now) and instead use a `List<string>` as your desired storage.

That way you can add all the SQL statements into this list, and then afterwards decide how many to lump together in one batch to send to the server or file, or whatever reason you have for splitting it.

In other words, here's what I would do:

```
list.Add("INSERT INTO enquete_antwoord (enquete_vraag_ID, enquete_antwoord, kdv_ID, semesterstart, semestereind, semester) VALUES ('" + reader2["enquete_vraag_ID"].ToString() + "', '" + antwoord + "', '" + id + "', 2013-12-12, 2014-12-12, 1)");
list.Add("INSERT INTO enquete_antwoord (enquete_vraag_ID, enquete_antwoord, kdv_ID, semesterstart, semestereind, semester) VALUES ('" + reader2["enquete_vraag_ID"].ToString() + "', '" + antwoord + "', '" + id + "', 2013-12-12, 2014-12-12, 1)");
list.Add("INSERT INTO enquete_antwoord (enquete_vraag_ID, enquete_antwoord, kdv_ID, semesterstart, semestereind, semester) VALUES ('" + reader2["enquete_vraag_ID"].ToString() + "', '" + antwoord + "', '" + id + "', 2013-12-12, 2014-12-12, 1)");
...

string first100 = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list.Take(100));
string next100 = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list.Skip(100).Take(100));
.. and so on, (use a loop for this though)
```

Other notes:

1. The way you write dates in that SQL is wrong, you need to write them up as strings with the right format
2. Make sure you add the necessary guarantees that you're not opening yourself up to injection attacks with this, as is always a chance when you concatenate SQL statements and values together as strings.

Answer (score 1):

this will work for sure

```
string[] commands = str.Split(new string[] { @")""" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```